# Stay on same page using php without javascript

Tags: php

I need to validate a form using php. when i go to validate i need it to stay on same page if validation fails. is this possible. i know it can be done with the use of javascript but im trying to cater to those who turn javascript off.

Comment: How are you going to do the validation without javascript?

Comment: Just post the form to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you're not willing to use Javascript, you'll have to submit the form (and go to a new page) to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the variables into strings, then use a post method to validate, and if there was a problem get the variables back out from the strings

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

<form action="validate.php" method="POST" value="$name">
<input type="text" id="name" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side code. In order to validate the page, you need to do a round trip to the server. If the form doesn't validate, then you can redirect them back to the same, page, along with some markup that explains the problem.

That said, [only ~1%](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html) of people disable javascript, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Even if you do perform client side form validation in javascript, you should always validate server side as well.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to do without client side help it is possible to emulate the result by posting the for to the page that hosts the form.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
       // validate your form and set placeholder variables for error messages.
       if(empty($_POST["username"])) $userError = "You must supply a username";

       // if the form is valid do a header redirect

       header("Location: http://mysite.com/myaccount/");

}
<form method='post'>
      <label for='username'>Username: </label>
      <input id='username' name='username' type='text' 
             value='<?= isset($_POST["username"])?$_POST["username"]:"" ?>'>
      <?= isset($userError)?$userError:"" ?>
</form>
```